# JSOM - Loading of multiple objects in one request possible?

Tags: 2010, jsom

Is there a way to load multiple objects in one request like this:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    this.web = context.get_web();
                    this.site = context.get_site();
                    var list = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.sessionStorage.getItem('selectedContentType'));
                    var query = '<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'><Query>' + $('.camlQuery').val() + '</Query></View>';
                    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
                    this.items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
                    context.load(this.site);
                    context.load(this.items, 'Include(ID,DocIcon,LinkFilename,FileRef,FileLeafRef,Title,ContentType,SupplierPGProduct)');
                    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, get_Data_onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, get_Data_onFailure));
                }
```

In this example, I mean `this.site` and `this.items` in one async request?
Or do I have to load first `this.site` and when the request is successful, then load the `this.items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what you're doing in your code.

`context.load` isn't doing a request, it's just queuing it up for a coming  `context.executeQueryAsync` which is doing the request.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. That means, when I say `context.load(this.site);` and `context.load(this.items);` both objects are loaded, when I `executeQueryAsync`? That would be perfect!

Comment: That's how it works